# Show $f$ is zero almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

Suppose $f:[a,b]\times[c,d]\to [0,\infty)$ is Riemann integrable and $\int_{[a,b]\times [c,d]}f=0$. If $m$ is the Lebesgue measure, and $S=\{(x,y): f(x,y)>0\}=0$.

My attempt: Define $S_n=\{(x,y): f(x,y)\geq\frac{1}{n}\}$. Then $S=\cup_nS_n$. Also, $S_1\subseteq S_2\subseteq ...$ and so $lim \ m(S_n)=m(S)$. By Chebyshev, $0\leq m(S_n)\leq n \int_{[a,b]\times [c,d]}f=0$. Therefore, $m(S)=0$ by the squeeze theorem.

Does this look correct? Thank you

Comment: Is $f $ a function  of one or two variables?

Comment: @PhoemueX two variables, I meant to put $[a,b]\times [c,d]$. I'll fix it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is right. Indeed, suppose $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mu)$ is a measure space, then for any nonnegative function, we have
$$
\int f\text{d}\mu=0 \leftrightarrow f=0, \mu-a.e
$$